# How to override core class which is already overrided by other custom module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, extend, conflict

How to override core class which is already overrided by other custom module

I have module1 and module2 overriding `CatalogSearch` module.

**in Module1**

**etc/di**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index" />
```

**in Controller class**

```
class Index extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{
 public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $catalogSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    QueryFactory $queryFactory


) {
     parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$resultPageFactory,$queryFactory,$layerResolver);
     $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
     $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
     $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
     $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

**In Module2**

**etc/di**

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module2\Controller\Result\Index" />
```

**In Controller class**

```
 class Index extends \Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index
 {
    public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $catalogSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    Http $request,
    LayoutInterface $layout,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
     Resolver $layerResolver,     
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $catalogCategoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Vendor\Module1\Model\Client\Connector $tglssearchClientConnector,
    QueryFactory $queryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$storeManager,$queryFactory,$layerResolver);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->catalogCategoryFactory = $catalogCategoryFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->tglssearchClientConnector = $tglssearchClientConnector;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

    /* parent::__construct(
        $context
    ); */
}
```

I get below error,

> Argument 4 passed to Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory, instance of Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_5test\app\code\Vendor\Module2\Controller\Result\Index.php on line 36 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_5test\app\code\Vendor\Module1\Controller\Result\Index.php on line 22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Module **ONE** is overriding some core class, if you want to override
>   same core class already used/override module **ONE**, override Module
>   ONE class by using your module( Module Two )as below example.

**Module ONE as Vendor/Module**

`Vendor/Module` is extending `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result`

In di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Result"/>
</config>
```

In Block result.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;


/**
 * Product search result block
 */
class Result extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result
{
   public function getSearchQueryText()
    {

die('Module ONE');
// Some code
return parent::getSearchQueryText();
    }

}
```

**Module TWO as Vendor/Moduletwo**

`Vendor/Moduletwo` is extending `Vendor\Module\Block\Result`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Moduletwo\Block\Result"/>
</config>
```

In block result.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Moduletwo\Block;


/**
 * Product search result block
 */
class Result extends \Vendor\Module\Block\Result
{
   public function getSearchQueryText()
    {

die('TWO');
// Some code
return parent::getSearchQueryText();
    }

}
```

**In this case both extension functionalities will work.**

Comment: I have followed the above mentioned procedure @Krishna, i get the error in the updated answer

Comment: @krishna can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300095/magento-2-how-to-override-member-variable

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, correct the sequence of the arguments in the `parent::__construct(arg1, arg2, . . .)` method. It must be same as it is in the parent's `__construct()`.

so, to remove this error :

change

```
parent::__construct($context, $catalogSession, $storeManager, $queryFactory, $layerResolver);
```

to

```
parent::__construct($context, $catalogSession, $storeManager, $resultPageFactory, $layerResolver, $queryFactory);
```

this should solve the mentioned error.