# How to call Plugin which already using the preference for vendor file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, plugin, compare, preference

How to call Plugin which already using the preference for vendor file in magento 2. I have already has preference which is overridding the some custom Magento controller, Now how can i use plugin to call my around method action in di.xml for same controller Action, can any one has any idea.
Thank In Advance.

Comment: Can you tell me what you have try archive using this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the plugin for the Controller which is overriding the vendor file.

You can try this method as well:
[How to override core class which is already overrided by other custom module in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136852/how-to-override-core-class-which-is-already-overrided-by-other-custom-module-in)

Comment: I need to overrride Controller Files But in the link he has explained block override, Is it Worth? @xMagestore

Comment: It was just for a reference. you can override the controller in a similar way.

Comment: I know overridding the module with custom module using another preference but here i need is plugin for already overriden perference, can you answer my question?

Comment: Yes, suppose the core class A is overridden in B, then You can create a plugin for class B which would work efficiently.

Comment: then how would i define that in di.xml, i tried but it not calling the plugin method ,can You please mention the di.xml file how to use. @xMageStore

Comment: Please tell me the classes that you are referring. I will create a di.xml

Comment: /*Preference code overridden code */<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add" type="vendor\modulename\Controller\Catalog\Product\Compare\Add" />
/*Plugin code */
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add">
        <plugin name="LimitToCompareProducts"
                type="vendor1\Module1\Model\Plugin\Compare\list.php"/>
    </type>

Answer (score 0):

use **sortOrder** in plugin declaration :

```
<config>
  <type name="{ObservedType}">
    <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

Comment: if i use sort Order what would happen can You explain it clear @Prasanta Hatui

Comment: When multiple Plugin has declare for same method then the sortOrder is used  which plugins will run first.

Comment: I have Plugin and Preference concept not both are plugins in my scenerio @Prasanta Hatui

Comment: In this case you will only can use for overridden  class method to change the behavior

Comment: is their any change to use both preference and plugin Concept @Prasanta Hatui

Comment: @Prince Patel Please to solve these