# How to add new grid in product form in magento2

Tags: grid, magento2.3, php-7.2

How to add custom grid exactly related products grid in admin product form Magento2.

I want to insert custom grid under related product grid. That grid is a exact copy of related product concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created same grid as **"related products"** using below free extension.

Please check below link

[Click here](https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_ProductRelation)

Comment: Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento23/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\ProcessSourceItemsAfterSaveAssociatedLinks->afterSaveProductRelations(Object(Boolfly\ProductRelation\Model\Catalog\Product\Link\Interceptor), NULL, Object(Boolfly\ProductRelation\Model\Product\Interceptor))

Comment: have you did, upgrade, compile and deploy ?

Comment: yeah ...........

Comment: resolve this issue here  :https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136852/how-to-override-core-class-which-is-already-overrided-by-other-custom-module-in

Comment: is this working now ?

Comment: yes.. return is missing in this file

Comment: ok all the best :)

Comment: @ManoM in which file and where ?

Comment: In Model\Catalog\Product\Link, add return $this in end of the saveProductRelations() function. @Mukesh