# Magento 2 : How to Override Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox in two different modules?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides

I'm overriding a **`Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox`** in my two different modules.

> **Vendor\Module1\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module1\Block\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

> **Vendor\Module2\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module2\Block\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

> Both Class Overrides the same method 
>   `wrapResult($html)`.

**It only shows the output of Module2, not both modules output at the same time. I've installed the Conflict detector Extension to see the confliction which shows something like this.**

[image: Screenshot]

What I've tried so far,

[How to override core class which is already overrided by other custom module in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136852/how-to-override-core-class-which-is-already-overrided-by-other-custom-module-in)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Vendor\Module1\Block\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module2\Block\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

**but it gives me the error as shown below,**

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred
>   when creating object:
>   Vendor\Module2\Block\FinalPriceBox\Interceptor

### UPDATE

I've tried using a plugin but it shows only one module's output.

> **Vendor\Module1\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="vendor_module1_finalpricebox" type="Vendor\Module1\Plugin\FinalPriceBox" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

> **Vendor\Module2\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
     <plugin name="vendor_module2_finalpricebox" type="Vendor\Module2\Plugin\FinalPriceBox" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

**Let me know if anyone has a solution.**

Comment: @mohitRana

Use plugin instead of preference

Comment: I've tried using a plugin but it shows only one module's output.

Comment: Set different sort order of plugin.

Comment: it gives me **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface in /var/www/html/magento_233/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50**

Comment: can you display code for this Vendor\Module2\Plugin\FinalPriceBox

Comment: Code is too long and for your information, I'm using this plugin for **aroundToHtml**